# PHP Help woth regular expression, from first string to last string

Tags: php, expression

Can anyone help me to write preg_replace regular expression for cleaning some text.

I have many URL like this

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=bzS6UMKFKcfZ4QTN0YDIBg&amp;ved=0CB0QFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHE2IgCwu8N2aauurN6HW6YjgILgQ">
```

So, I want to delete from

```
&amp;
```

to

```
">
```

Can you tell me how to do this with regular expression please.

Comment: I have try this preg_replace("/^\&amp;sa.*\"$/","",$bodytag);

Comment: Why do you match at the beginning (`^`) and at the end of the string (`$`)? From your sample string it looks like, this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love&sa=U&ei=bzS6UMKFKcfZ4QTN0YDIBg&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHE2IgCwu8N2aauurN6HW6YjgILgQ">';

$string = preg_replace('/"(http[^&]+)&[^"]+"/', '"$1"', $string);

echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=bzS6UMKFKcfZ4QTN0YDIBg&amp;ved=0CB0QFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNHE2IgCwu8N2aauurN6HW6YjgILgQ">';

$regex = '(&amp;.+">)Ui'; // THE REGULAR EXPRESSION
$replacement = ''; // YOU CAN PLACE HERE YOUR REPLACEMENT IF NEEDED

$clean_url = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $url);

var_dump($clean_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression.

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '&amp;'))
   . substr($string, strpos($string, '>'));
```